# My output results are 0 in C++. What could be the issue

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void getInput(string name, float weekly_Pay){
    cout << "Please enter customer name" << endl;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Enter weekly salary" << endl;
    cin >> weekly_Pay;
}

void calcFedTaxes(float weekly_Pay,float PIT_Rate, float SOSEC_Rate, float PIT, float SOSEC){
    PIT = weekly_Pay * PIT_Rate; 
    SOSEC = weekly_Pay * SOSEC_Rate;
}

void calcNetPay(float weekly_Pay, float PIT, float SOSEC, float weekly_Net_Pay){
    weekly_Net_Pay = weekly_Pay - (PIT + SOSEC);
}

void displayInfo(string name, float PIT, float SOSEC, float weekly_Net_Pay){
    cout << "Customer name is:" << name << endl;
    cout << "PIT is:" << PIT << endl;
    cout << "SOSEC is:" << SOSEC << endl;
    cout << "Weekly Pay is:" << weekly_Net_Pay << endl;
}

int main(){
    char response = 'n';
    string name =""; 
    float weekly_Pay = 0.0;
    float weekly_Net_Pay = 0.0;
    const float PIT_RATE = (0.2); 
    const float SOSEC_RATE = (0.08); 
    float SOSEC = (0.0);
    float PIT = (0.0);

    do {
        getInput(name, weekly_Pay);
        calcFedTaxes (weekly_Pay, PIT_RATE, SOSEC_RATE, PIT, SOSEC);
        calcNetPay (weekly_Pay, PIT, SOSEC, weekly_Net_Pay);
        displayInfo (name, PIT, SOSEC, weekly_Net_Pay);

        cout << "Enter n or N to end:";
        cin >> response;
        cout << endl;
    }
    while (!((response == 'n')  || (response == 'N')));
}
```

Comment: None of your functions that calculate results have the result as an output parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Your functions are taking their output parameters *by value*, so they are acting on *copies* of the variables that `main()` passes to them.  Any changes the functions make to the parameters are *not* reflected back to `main()`.

To do what you are attempting, you need to pass output parameters *by reference* instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void getInput(string &name, float &weekly_Pay){
    cout << "Please enter customer name" << endl;
    cin >> name;
    cout << "Enter weekly salary" << endl;
    cin >> weekly_Pay;
}

void calcFedTaxes(float weekly_Pay, float PIT_Rate, float SOSEC_Rate, float &PIT, float &SOSEC){
    PIT = weekly_Pay * PIT_Rate; 
    SOSEC = weekly_Pay * SOSEC_Rate;
}

void calcNetPay(float weekly_Pay, float PIT, float SOSEC, float &weekly_Net_Pay){
    weekly_Net_Pay = weekly_Pay - (PIT + SOSEC);
}

void displayInfo(string name, float PIT, float SOSEC, float weekly_Net_Pay){
    cout << "Customer name is:" << name << endl;
    cout << "PIT is:" << PIT << endl;
    cout << "SOSEC is:" << SOSEC << endl;
    cout << "Weekly Pay is:" << weekly_Net_Pay << endl;
}

int main(){
    char response = 'n';
    string name =""; 
    float weekly_Pay = 0.0;
    float weekly_Net_Pay = 0.0;
    const float PIT_RATE = (0.2); 
    const float SOSEC_RATE = (0.08); 
    float SOSEC = (0.0);
    float PIT = (0.0);

    do {
        getInput(name, weekly_Pay);
        calcFedTaxes (weekly_Pay, PIT_RATE, SOSEC_RATE, PIT, SOSEC);
        calcNetPay (weekly_Pay, PIT, SOSEC, weekly_Net_Pay);
        displayInfo (name, PIT, SOSEC, weekly_Net_Pay);

        cout << "Enter n or N to end:";
        cin >> response;
        cout << endl;
    }
    while (!((response == 'n')  || (response == 'N')));
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/25gr2T)